# Subsonic how do I filter a loaded collection?

Tags: subsonic

Currently I am using Subsonic 2.1  and .NET 2.1 and I have an issue where I am attempting to filter a pre-loaded collection with 300+ items. I am using the following to attempt to preform the filter:

**orders = MasterOrders.Where("account", mbrAccount).Load();**

The end results is setting orders equal to the entire MasterOrders collection and not the filtered results. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting Dotnet Framework 3.5 you can use a LINQ select-query. Then convert it to a List<MasterOrder>.

Comment: Since I am not using 3.5 are there any other alternatives?